# Jenkins in Docker sharing docker.sock

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration

In order to set up a Jenkins CI pipeline, I run Jenkins in a Docker container, configured to build with Docker Cloud Agents. So, I have one container that runs the Jenkins master, and *n* containers that pop up to embrace a build request. The pipeline had to build Docker images, push them and update Docker services, I didn't use DinD to do this, but installed Docker in the Docker Cloud Agents, and adopted the shared (via Docker volume) docker.sock file solution. Are there some bad consequences? I read a good article here (the solution I adopted is clearly described in the last section): https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/